# How can you check whether domain exists or not in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose my email address is `xyz@yahoo.com` and I want to check if `yahoo.com` is a valid domain or not.

Can anyone tell me which Java API I can use for this?

Comment: You want to check if it is a valid email address as well, maybe?

Comment: You can't check if a domain is valid or not. Or, well, you could check if the format is valid, but that doesn't mean that the domain exists.

Comment: maybe you can 1. check if DOMAIN.TLD can be resolved by **DNS Server**, if can, then it's a valid domain. 2. check the result from **internic.net whois** service, such as http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=yahoo.com&type=domain

Comment: Can you find an internic that works for all top domains? The one that you linked to does not support ".st"

Answer (score 11):

`InetAddress` has [`getByName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) method to determine the IP address of a host, given the host's name.

If no IP address for the host could be found ( in case the given host name is not valid) , [`UnknownHostException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html)  will be thrown.

So , you just try to catch an `UnknownHostException` when calling `InetAddress.getByName()` . If `UnknownHostException` is caught , that means your input host name is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that you could do is trying to resolve "yahoo.com". Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("yahoo.com");
    System.out.println(inetAddress.getHostName());
    System.out.println(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
}
```

which outputs:

```
yahoo.com
67.195.160.76
```

Comment: You might get false positives as far as I know. I'm behind a proxy so I can't test that code, but e.g. everything under the domain ".st" answers you are using a browser. You could e.g. text adjlafdjlks.st

Comment: @Kaj: could you explain why? I've tried my code with "adjlafdjlks.st" and the answer that I get (195.178.160.40) is exactly the same that `nslookup adjlafdjlks.st` returns.

Comment: Yes, and that means that you get false positives. All domains that are unregistered under the ".st" domain are considered as valid since they are directed to the domain registrar for that domain. Hence everything will return an address, but that does not mean that they are valid and in use.

Comment: @Kaj: well, since `nslookup` has the same behaviour, I guess this is an exception rather than a false positive. If there are domains like this, you may add a black-list of hostname, for which the check fails (maybe with a specific exception)

Comment: That's why I have said in this thread, that you can't create a domain check solution that works for all domains. ".st" isn't the only top domain that is handled like that. I have never seen a good valid reason to why someone would like to check if a domain is valid or not.

Comment: You are supposing that the domain already exist not just a semantical validation

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to check the MX of the entered domain.

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

It is not Java API, but you can always parse the HTML response.

It means if the provider of the mail service is not blacklisted it could be safe and a real address.

But as already said, some server could always define security restriction to such service.

Another point, some services exist to provide temporary emails (mailinator.com, jetable.org, and so on...) You have to check these domains as well if you want to prevent a user to register with such an email.

**UPDATE**

Google provides a [DNS check site](https://dns.google.com/query) which seems to be free.

An example: https://dns.google/resolve?name=amazon.com&type=MX returns a page with the following JSON:

```
{
  "Status": 0,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "amazon.com.",
      "type": 15
    }
  ],
  "Answer": [
    {
      "name": "amazon.com.",
      "type": 15,
      "TTL": 724,
      "data": "5 amazon-smtp.amazon.com."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator.

First add maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

then:

```
boolean isValid = DomainValidator.getInstance().isValid("yahoo.com");
```

Comment: This is not what he asked.

Comment: not to validate format, but whether  it  can resolve to correct ip

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if it's the best way to this, but I've done something similar for a VB.NET program:

I just pinged the domain, and if I didn't get a reply, the domain either was offline or didn't exist.

Comment: There are lots and lots of domains that don't answer to ping because of security concerns.

Comment: It don't give a lot of information about how to do this in Java.