# How to check validity of a subdomain in java?

Tags: java, networking, dns, subdomain

I have a domain abc.jp 
For example:
 I want to check if this is valid to that I can add another sublevel domain to this example. How to do it? If possible, upload some java codes as reference please? 
Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5933518/5749 A code example on your part would be great!

Comment: @Pullie 
When I use InetAddress and I test abc.jp, it displays **ok**.
But when I use ac.jp, it displays **failed** . However, **ac.jp** exists (for example: [link](http://www.iuj.ac.jp/))

Code: 
`import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "ac.jp";
  
  try {
   InetAddress iaddr = InetAddress.getByName(input);
   System.out.println("ok");
  } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
   System.out.println("failed");
  }
 }
 
}`

Comment: ah ok. I see what you mean. I think Whois will serve you here, since you cannot do a DNS lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example ac.jp is a valid domain, but not an IP resolvable domain. So I would suggest a whois server. You would need to keep a number of whois servers if you want to check all domains. If you only do Japan then the below snippet should work™.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.whois.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhoisClient whois = new WhoisClient();
        String whoishost = "whois.jprs.jp";
       // String whoishost = "whois.verisign-grs.com"; // for .com domains
        String domain = "ac.jp";
        try {
            whois.connect(whoishost);
            String whoisData = whois.query(domain);
            if (whoisData.toUpperCase().contains("NO MATCH")){
                System.out.println("Domain is not registered. According to whoishost: " + whoishost);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Domain is registered. According to whoishost: " + whoishost);
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioex) {
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your positive response. Now I need to test for another ccTLD; that is the .mu

As per your code listing above, you included this piece:
`String whoishost = "whois.verisign-grs.com"; // for .com domains`

Do you know the String for **whoishost** for .mu domain? If not, please let me know where I can find it.

Comment: He @Tashley that is basic Google skills. Put some effort in it.   http://www.nirsoft.net/whois_servers_list.html

Comment: Thank you very much mate. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Guava's [`InternetDomainName`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html) provides a good solution to this problem.

```
String input = "abc.jp";
InternetDomainName domain = InternetDomainName.from(input);
InternetDomainName subdomain = domain.child("www");
subdomain.toString(); // "www.abc.jp";
```

If the input domain or the subdomain are invalid you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can also do checks like `domain.isUnderPublicSuffix()`, depending on how much validation you want.

Comment: It does not validate the domain.
I tried it with another ccTLD; that is the .mu
it generates **InternetDomainName{name=qqq.mu}** even though this domain does not exist.

Anyways, thanks for your attempt to solve my problem.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question. I interpreted "valid" as "well-formed and containing only valid characters". I didn't realise that you also want to check that it is a real domain on the internet.