# Apache Commons Validator - Validate VPN (Sub)Domain

Tags: validation, subdomain, java-7, apache-commons

I work for a company that has a VPN set up. Computers on the (Windows ActiveDomain/LDAP) network can be accessed either by name (`\\machine`) or subdomain (`\\machine.companyname.tld`;  eg: `ahammerthief.acme.net`).

I'm trying to use Apache Commons Validator to recognise `machine.companyname.tld` as a valid domain/subdomain, despite the fact that it's not available from outside the company in which I work.

Is it possible to do this or is Validator not meant to do this?

The code I have is as follows:

```
String domain = null, in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    null, "Please enter the domain:", "NTLM/Samba Domain", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
);
if (null != in && !in.isEmpty()) {
  DomainValidator validator = DomainValidator.getInstance(true);
  // Always returns false. Why?
  if (validator.isValidGenericTld(in) || validator.isValidLocalTld(in)) {
    domain = in;
    UniAddress addr = null;
    try {
      addr = UniAddress.getByName(domain, true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException UHEx) {
      System.err.println("Unknown Host (\"" + domain + "\": " + UHEx.getMessage());
      UHEx.printStackTrace(System.err);
      return;
    }
    // ... Ask user for credentials here. Never gets this far.
    // TODO: Use credentials to create/overwrite a jCIFS SMBFile on the network
  } else {
    System.err.println("Entered domain (" + in + ") is invalid!");
  }
} else {
  System.err.println("Entered domain is null or empty!");
}
```

The text I'm entering when prompted is of the form `subdomain.companyname.tld`

I *could* use a regex to check that there are at least two '.' characters in the supplied string and that they're preceded by at least one character that isn't '.', but I am of the opinion that if Validator has classes for validating domains and URLs, I should be able to use it for this purpose.

**UPDATE:** I have subsequently looked at the following questions:

1. [How to check validity of a subdomain in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149429/how-to-check-validity-of-a-subdomain-in-java)
2. [How can you check whether domain exists or not in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933277/how-can-you-check-whether-domain-exists-or-not-in-java). [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884882/2225787) suggests using `isValid()` from `DomainValidator`. I will try that to see if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you check whether domain exists or not in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933277/how-can-you-check-whether-domain-exists-or-not-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method/function to use for validating a domain/subdomain is `validator.isValid(String in)`, not `validator.isValidGenericTld( String in)` or  `validator.isValidLocalTld(String in)`. Those last two only validate the portion after the last period ('.').

In the above, `validator` is an instance of `DomainValidator`.