# How to check if given URL exists or not in Java and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, validation, url

I am trying to check if an URL exists or not and currently using this validator:

```
boolean isValid = URLUtil.isValidUrl( "https://www.googlesgger.com/" );
```

1. https://www.google.com         // valid URL
2. https://www.googlesgger.com/   // actually it's not a valid URL, but it shows a valid URL

Actually it validates http or https  and www and .com (it checks the URL contains http or https and www and .com not validate given URL is valid or not)

Kindly help me how to check if the given full URL is valid or not.

Comment: so you want to check whether this url is having any content or not?

Comment: `https://www.googlesgger.com/` is a valid url but not an existing domain, you need to check something else

Comment: yes@Sauravkumar

Comment: you confused "valid url" with "existing domain", so you asked for the wrong thing. guess that's why.

Comment: Are you asking a java or JavaScript question?

Comment: I think, [that could be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933277/how-can-you-check-whether-domain-exists-or-not-in-java) what you're searching for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you check whether domain exists or not in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933277/how-can-you-check-whether-domain-exists-or-not-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code tries to connect with specified url , if successfully connected, proceed ahead and prints "URL exists"; otherwise, UnknownHostException is thrown and you can handle the situation in catch block as shown:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class URLExists
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
            urlc.connect();//<--- throws UnknownHostException when unable to connect!!
            System.out.println("URL exists");           
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.out.println("URL either doesn't exist or unable to connect at this moment");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: how to ignore http and https from given url because  if we give "http://www.google.com" full url only it validate,if i give "www.google.com" ith throws error

Comment: This will check if you are able to create a connection to a URL, by no means it will identify a valid URL as you stated in your question

Comment: if you are able to connect to a URL , it means it exists!! you can't connect to a non-existing url. so , if you can connect, you can tell, URL exists for sure. however, we can't be sure if URL doesn't exists for sure as it may be temporarily down or you are not connected to the internet!

Answer (score -3):

if by "URL exists" you mean "URL redirects to a valid web page", you'll have to check the HTTP return code so you need to find some way to make HTTP requests and check the return code, 200 being a valid response.

This is probably doable in Java, and JavaScript as well, depending on what kind of application it is... if you're using client-side JS you might run into some hiccups since browser-side JS is *really* not intended for making cross-domain calls

Comment: What are you talking about? "Browser-side JS" is very much intended for making cross domain calls as proven by it's `fetch` API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or the older XMLHttpRequest. It's quite literally at the root of many applications, fetching data from (external) API's